# PHP Connect to restAPI With SSL Certificate

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I'm having some issues with my case. the API owner sent me a public certificate "Certificate.cer" file. how do I sent it with my request as I don't have private keys and a ".pem" file?

The owner sent the following info:

```
a) https://api:555
b) 123.33.33.33 22
c)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDdTCCAl2gAwIBAgIIAT/qgbl0WggwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwSjEQMA4GA1UE
---------------
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Ask the API provider what you're supposed to do with the certificate, because we don't know either.

Comment: Call REST API https with certificate, key and CAcertificate

Comment: Again, ask the provider of the API for specific instructions.